# Bloquear .click() em um label

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
$("input[type='radio'][class='tipo']").click(function() {           

url = $(this).attr('data-route');    
id = $(this).attr('id');   

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        'model' : $(this).val()
    },

    beforeSend: function () {
    },

    success: function (response) {
        
        if (response !== null) {
            
            response.forEach(function(field, i) {
                 $("div."+field.field).show().find("input, select, radio").attr("required", "req");
            })

            id === "mm"
                ?  (
                    $("label#bdj1").click(),
                    $("label#bdj2").prop("title","Essa máquina só aceita 1 bandeja"),
                    $("label#bdj2").off("click")
                   )
                :  (
                    $("label#bdj2").prop("title", ""),
                    $("label#bdj2").on("click",function() { 
                        return true; 
                    })
                   )
        }

    }
});

});
```

```css
div.btnyesno > input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
div.btnyesno {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
}
div.btnyesno > div.containerball {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 500px;
}
div.btnyesno > div.containerball > div.ball {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    left: 50px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #ccc;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 500px;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
div.btnyesno > label{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.btnyesno > label.yes {
    left: -10px;
}
div.btnyesno > label.no {
    right: -10px;
}
#bloq:checked ~ #label {
  left: 5px !important;
}
#desboq:checked ~ #label {
  right: 5px !important;
}       
.btnYes {
    left: 5px !important;
}
.btnNo {
    right: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input 
 type='radio' 
 class='tipo' 
 name='tipo' 
 id='m5' 
 data-route='https://mvca.com.br/admn/choice/model' 
 value='m5'
>Pneumática D 430

<input 
type='radio' 
class='tipo' 
name='tipo' 
id='ac' 
data-route='https://mvca.com.br/admn/choice/model' 
value='ac'
>Acessórios

<div class="bandejas">
    <label>Bandejas</label>
    <div class="btnyesno">
        <input type="radio" name="bandejas" id="bdj_1" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="bandejas" id="bdj_2" value="2">
        <label role="button" for="bdj_1" id="bdj1" class="yes">1</label>
        <div class="containerball"> 
            <div class="ball"></div>
        </div>
        <label role="button" for="bdj_2" id="bdj2" class="no">2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Preciso desativar a chamada ao evento **.click()** mas no **LABEL**

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Não funcionou!

Já tentei **return** e **return false**. Também não funciona!

Alguma orientação?

**EDIT:**

Funciona assim, tenho um grupo de **radio-buttons** com o mesmo **name**. Ok! Mas aqui só coloquei 2 para não poluir.

Ao clicar no **radio** que tem **value = "mm"**, então preciso desativar o **label**

**EDIT 2**:

Experimentei assim

```
id === "mm"
    ?  (
        $("label#bdj1").click(),
        $("label#bdj2").prop("title","Essa máquina só aceita 1 bandeja"),
        $("label#bdj2").off("click")
        )
    :  (
        $("label#bdj2").prop("title", ""),
        $("label#bdj2").on("click", function(){
            console.log("Teste.....");
        })
```

Antes de selecionar o radio **button** que é igual a **"mm"**, o botão funciona normalmente, tanto para um lado quanto para o outro.

No entanto, ao selecionar o botão **"mm"**, o `off()` ocorre corretamente. Então, ao selecionar novamente uma opção diferente de **"mm"**, então, é exibida a mensagem

```
teste.....
```

Ou seja, o **click** funcionou. Mas o **botão** (**a bolinha**) não corre para a direita!

Comment: Se quer remover um evento é com [`jquery.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: Cara funcionou. Mas quando clico em outra opção é preciso liberar o evento. Seria .*.on("click")*? Tentei e não deu!

Comment: Já tentei essas 2 opções e não funcionarm  $("label#bdj2").on("click",function() { 
                            return true; 
                        }),
                        $("label#bdj2").bind("click")

Comment: Reinstale o evento da mesma  forma `$("label#bdj2").on('click',.......` . Se não me engano o `bind()` foi depreciado.

Comment: seria returm true??? onde está os .......

Comment: Tentei assim já e não restaurou. $("label#bdj2").on("click",function() { 
    return true; 
}). Na verdade eu preciso agora restaurar o evento para que quando for chamado, esteja disponivel

Comment: Modifique o MCVE para ver como está fazendo para eu ter uma noção de como o ajudar.

Comment: Fiz as alterações e adicionei comentários ao final da pergunta! Detalhe: www.mcva.com.br é apenas um VirualHost do Apache. Mas isso nada tem a ver com a dúvida ok?

Comment: @AugustoVasques. Fiz as alterações você que solicitou.

Comment: Cara pq vc não coloca simplesmente um CSS de `pointer-events: none;` na label?

Comment: então,@hugocsl funcionou. mas eu preciso do $("label#bdj2").prop("title","Essa máquina só aceita 1 bandeja"), funcionando e esse recurso está bloqueando o title. Existe algum recurso para isso?